# Javascript date displaying/returning incorrect date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here. But if someone could help me out that would be great.

I've hard coded a date string and I'm trying to create a javascript date object. After creating a string from the newly created javascript date object, I noticed that the date object is incorrect. But the string is good.

```
var str = '2014-06-24'; // hard coded string yyyy-mm-dd
var new_day = new Date(str);
var date_string = new_day.getFullYear()+"-"+(new_day.getMonth()+1)+"-"+(new_day.getDate()+1);

alert('these are supposed to match: '+ date_string+" \n"+new_day);
```

Is there something I'm missing in regards to js date objects? Help. [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tcr2nv21/11/) Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Use `.getUTCFullYear()`, `.getUTCMonth()` and `.getUTCDate()` to get the UTC date that you passed in.

Comment: Consider using a JS library like `moment.js`

Comment: It also depends on client machine date time format right??

Comment: @Bergi thank you for posting a proper suggestion. however, it looks like it still returns the incorrect date. :\

Comment: @Modelesq: I didn't realise at first, but what is that `+1` doing there after the `getDate`? Only months are zero-based in JS

Comment: @Modelesq ouch. I do recommend using a library, as dealing with timezones can be a right headache.

Comment: @evolutionxbox i meant no disrespect. It's not my project to implement moment.js so I'm making due with whats given kinda thing.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: You can also choose to ignore timezones and use UTC for everything :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm writing a second answer.  My first one was wrong.*

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters), You really shouldn't be using a dateString as the constructor argument to set your date "due to browser differences and inconsistencies".  That being said, you are also running into major issues because of timezone differences.  In your example, you have the following result (in chrome and in CDT timezone):

> these are supposed to match: 2014-6-24
>   Mon Jun 23 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)

But if you'll notice, it is the same.  It's `2014-6-24` minus 5 hours due to timezone difference if the user is in CDT timezone.  That results in the `Jun 23 2014 19:00:00` bit.  If your original date of `2014-6-24` is truly without a timezone, you should be instantiating the date object as a UTC date object.

```js
var new_day = new Date(Date.UTC(2014,05,24)); /* month adjusted for zero-based index */
var date_string = new_day.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+(new_day.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-"+(new_day.getUTCDate());
alert('these are supposed to match: '+ date_string+" \n"+new_day.toUTCString());
```

The huge difference between this and my deleted answer is that you could have set the date string in my first answer to `2014-06-24 20:00` and it would have resulted in an incorrect time.  That issue doesn't occur with this code.  With the above example, `Date.UTC(2014,05,24,20)` doesn't result in a `25th` date for the printed values.

#### Edit:

If you are relatively certain the date format will not change, you can add a quick adapter to pass the right parameters to the UTC method.

```js
var str = '2014-06-24'; // hard coded string yyyy-mm-dd
str = str.split('-'); // split into an array [2014,06,24]
str[1]--; // month (second array item) adjusted for zero-based index
var dateTime = Date.UTC.apply(null, str);  /* formatted as an integer to represent
                                              the UTC date of 2014-06-24. I use apply
                                              so I can pass the arguments as an array
                                              like object. */

var new_day = new Date(dateTime); 
var date_string = new_day.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+(new_day.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-"+(new_day.getUTCDate());
alert('these are supposed to match: '+ date_string+" \n"+new_day.toUTCString());
```

Comment: Does Date.UTC(2014,05,24) need to be in the form of '2014,05,24'. I only ask because the card coded date is '2014-06-24'.

Comment: @Modelesq [It does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) with a minimum of year and month paramters.  It shouldn't be too hard to adapt the string to that format if you need to.  I'll ad a quick adapter to my answer.